# Parsing special character issue

Tags: objective-c

When i try to parse special char  like "care&love", it just shows "care", the part after "&" truncated How can i make it to show the complete string???

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSString *postJson = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json=%@", jsonRequest];

NSData *requestData = [postJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

Comment: please be more specific: which string is truncated ?

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis the part after & character is truncated, for example "EL- STR 261: HAUL & SPOT", in this string SPOT is truncated..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Cocoa's built-in JSON serialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This would rule out improper string escaping (which is most likely the problem in your current code).

Sample:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"json": @"EL- STR 261: HAUL & SPOT"};
NSData* requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we are speaking about the value of jsonRequest, you have to URL encode that string before passing it to the postJson, otherwise & is seen as parameter separator.

json=care&love is interpreted as json="care" and love="" by the receiving server.

Url encoding the value will look like json=love%26care and will be decoded by the server as json="love&care"

use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding  for escaping, see at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: